# Single bit random number generator

Tags: random, verilog, test-bench

I am trying to generate single bit random number on every clock cycle in Verilog for testing purposes. I am doing this in a testbench module. Here is the code;

```
module tb;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg in;

// Outputs
wire x;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
single_bit uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .in(in), 
    .x(x)
);

integer seed=1;
initial
 begin
  clk=0;
  forever
    #5 clk=!clk;
        in= $random(seed);
end

endmodule
```

But after simulation, I am getting constant value of 1 in `seed`, and `in` has x.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is misleading.  Here is how your code is parsed:

```
initial begin
    clk=0;
    forever #5 clk=!clk;
    in= $random(seed);
end
```

Your code never reaches the assignment to `in` because you never reach the end of your `forever` loop.  Since you declared `in` as a `reg` and you never assign a value to `in`, it retains its default value of x.

The assignment to `in` should be inside the `forever` loop.  This generates a random stream of 0 and 1 for `in` at every clock edge:

```
initial begin
    clk=0;
    forever begin
        #5 clk=!clk;
        in = $random(seed);
    end
end
```